# Checking HTTP headers with asyncio and aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await

This is one of my first attempts to do something practical with [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). The task is simple:

> Given a list of URLs, determine if the content type is HTML for every URL.

I've used [`aiohttp`](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), initializing a single "session", ignoring SSL errors and issuing HEAD requests to avoid downloading the whole endpoint body. Then, I simply check if `text/html` is inside the `Content-Type` header string:

```
import asyncio

import aiohttp


@asyncio.coroutine
def is_html(session, url):
    response = yield from session.head(url, compress=True)
    print(url, "text/html" in response.headers["Content-Type"])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    links = ["https://httpbin.org/html",
             "https://httpbin.org/image/png",
             "https://httpbin.org/image/svg",
             "https://httpbin.org/image"]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)
    with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn, loop=loop) as session:
        f = asyncio.wait([is_html(session, link) for link in links])
        loop.run_until_complete(f)
```

The code works, it prints (the output order is inconsistent, of course):

```
https://httpbin.org/image/svg False
https://httpbin.org/image False
https://httpbin.org/image/png False
https://httpbin.org/html True
```

But, I'm not sure if I'm using `asyncio` loop, wait and coroutines, `aiohttp`'s connection and session objects appropriately. What would you recommend to improve?

Comment: Please rewrite to py3.6 with `async def` and `await`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO your code should look more like this:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
URLS = [...]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(*(foo(url) for url in URLS))))
```

Where individual URL is processed something like:

```
async def foo(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as s:
        async with s.head(...) as r:
            return url, r.headers[...]
```

Note separate session for each URL.

Additionally, exception handling may be needed, in which case, it should be encapsulated inside `foo`.